A question on positivity of eigenvalues for a matrix with some random chosen entries
Let $0<c<1$.
Is it possible to construct a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ with $a_{ii}=1$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$ and $a_{ij}\in ${$1, c$}  for all $i\neq j$ for some $n\geq 1$ such that $A$ has a negative eigenvalue?

When $n\ge3$, yes. Consider a matrix of the form
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&v^T\\ v&ee^T}
$$
where some elements of $v$ are equal to $c$ and some others are equal to $1$. Since $ee^T$ is positive semidefinite and singular but $v\not\in\operatorname{range}(ee^T)$ (because $v$ by construction is not parallel to $e$), $A$ cannot possibly be positive semidefinite. As $A$ is also nonzero, it must contain a negative eigenvalue.

I thought $a_{ij} \in {1, c}$ for $i \neq j$; the $ee^T$ block of $A$ has $a_{ij}=0$ for off-diagonal elements (I am assuming $e$ stands for some basis vector).

@TedBlack No. $e$ is a nearly standard notation for the vector of ones. $ee^T$ is a square matrix of ones.

I think, for novices like me, it would be helpful to add a brief explanation of why "...$A$ cannot possibly be positive semidefinite" given that $ee^T$ is a matrix of rank one and $v \notin \mathrm{range}(ee^T)$.

@TedBlack assuming familiarity with principal submatrices and signature,  the most basic approach is to focus on $n=3$ case and calculate $\det\big(A\big) = -(c-1)^2 \lt 0$ so $A$ is indefinite.  For $n\geq 4$ this means there is always a $3\times 3$ principal submatrix with determinant $= -(c-1)^2 \lt 0$ so again $A$ is indefinite.

@user8675309 thanks. I am aware of Sylvester's criterion for evaluating whether a symmetric matrix is positive definite. I just cannot connect it with $ee^T$ being positive semidefinite and singular and $v \notin \mathrm{range}(ee^T)$.

@TedBlack In general, for a symmetric matrix in the form of $A=\pmatrix{a&v^T\ v&B}$, if $v\not\in\operatorname{range}(B)$, then it has a nonzero component $u$ in $\ker(B)=\operatorname{range}(B)^\perp$. Therefore, for $x^T=(1,cu^T)$, the sign of $x^TAx=a+2cu^Tv$ is identical to the sign of $c$ when $|c|$ is sufficiently large. Hence $A$ is necessarily indefinite.
